# How to make ListView and other widgets scroll as a whole

Tags: android, listview

Iam have a layout like the below

```
    --scrollview--
    --linearlayout--
    --TextView--
    --TextView--
    --TextView--
    --TextView--
    --TextView--   
--edittext--
--edittext--
--edittext--
--edittext--
   --TextView--
   --listview--
--linearlayout--
--scrollview--
```

list view is scrolling seperatly with inner scroll, How to make the whole layout scroll with out list view inner scroll.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found any answer to be correct. Also if you have any difficulty to find a solution add comments so that others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. This is highly discouraged. Try to find another way to build the layout you want.

Answer (score 0):

It defeats the purpose of listView, when you want to disable scroll inside it. I would suggest you to inflate the views of your listView inside a vertical LinearLayout if you want to scroll it as a part of scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and see. I too had this same issue once. It solved my issue too.

Comment: i have changed it to RelativeLayout, but still have the same problem